# Dictionary with values as lists of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of lists

```
[[1,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,1,2,4],[0,1,2,3]]
```

and I would like to create a dictionary, where the keys are indices of list and the values are a list of tuples, such that

```
0 : [(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)]
1 : [(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)]
2 : [(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(2,4)]
```

and so on.

Is it possible to do so, using a comprehension? or without using too many nested loops?

Comment: It is. Show us what you’ve tried first. We’re not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [[1,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,1,2,4],[0,1,2,3]]
d = {ind: [(ind, v) for v in val] for ind, val in enumerate(l)}
```

here's the output

```
{0: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)],
 1: [(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)],
 2: [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4)],
 3: [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4)],
 4: [(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]}
```

Comment: so a comprehension inside a comprehension. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary can be created like this:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4],[0,2,3,4],[0,1,3,4],[0,1,2,4],[0,1,2,3]]
{i: [(i,j) for j in x[i] ] for i, _ in enumerate(x)}
```

It's easy if you build it step by step:

You need indices for dictionary keys (the `_` is for discarding the elements):

```
for i, _ enumerate(x)
```

You use them to build the dictionary:

```
{i: None for i, _ enumerate(x)}
```

Each value is a tuple and an element of `x[i]`

```
[(i,j) for j in x[i]]
```